# HTML5 Manifest through proxy

Tags: html, caching, proxy, manifest

We are using the HTML5 cache manifest mechanism. In some cases, clients using proxy do not get the latest front-end version, probably because the manifest file (and all other files) are cached on the client's organization proxy.

Is there a way to ensure that the manifest will not be cached on proxies?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, Try the below Code:

`window.applicationCache.status`

Similar Plugin may be useful https://github.com/meryn/connect-appcache-proxy